# adding a header to my navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a header as part of my navigation but below it like this: 
[image]

I have tried adding another row using bootstrap however it just comes out like this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">


         <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Bunk.</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           Menu
           <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
           <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#tenant">TENANT</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#landlord">LANDLORD</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#bunkfaqs">BUNK FAQs</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#blog">BLOG</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">TEAM</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#login">LOG IN</a>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
     <div class="row">
       <header id="header">
         <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
           <h2> Tenants </h2>
           </div>
         </div>
       </header>
     </div>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: *"header as part of my navigation"* -- what is the header supposed to do as "part of your navigation"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more about Bootstrap's [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) and [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

- The `navbar` should *only* contain [supported content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content).
- The header shouldn't be in the `navbar`, put it below.
- `.container` shouldn't be nested in other `.container`s.
- `.row` is meant to contain *only* `col-*`.

[Demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/v3GAq7EMOa)

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Bunk.</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            Menu
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#tenant">TENANT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#landlord">LANDLORD</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#bunkfaqs">BUNK FAQs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#blog">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">TEAM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#login">LOG IN</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-light">
    <header id="header" class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <h2 class="mx-auto">Tenants</h2>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: that leaves a gap between the header and the navbar

Comment: So if you want the navbar to overlay the header, then remove the body padding-top. That's how (fixed-top) position:fixed works.